# mysqli update fail query(displaying on url)

Tags: php

that show on url

Failed Query: UPDATE Member SET (Address, Mail, UserName, Password) WHERE ('123', 'asd', '123', '123')You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Address, Mail, UserName, Password) WHERE ('123', 'asd', '123', '123')' at line 1

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $address= $_POST['address'];
    $mail= $_POST['mail'];
    $user= $_POST['user'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    $sql= "UPDATE Member SET (Address, Mail, UserName, Password) WHERE 
        ('$address', '$mail', '$user', '$password')";
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `INSERT` instead?

Comment: You probably meant to use `$sql="INSERT INTO Member (Address, Mail, UserName, Password) VALUES ('$address', '$mail', '$user', '$password')";`

Comment: no, i have insert it first now im trying to do update

Comment: Well that's not how UPDATE works. Read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html

Comment: can you please tell me how that work?

Comment: If you want to update it should like this.                      sql= "UPDATE Member SET Address = '$address' WHERE Address = $address");

Comment: Follow what Mubo showed here. Yet it's hard to tell what you want to update and what your `WHERE` clause is.

Comment: when they have log-in and the user want to update their details.
$sql= "UPDATE Member SET (Address='', Mail='', UserName='', Password='') WHERE 
        $user";

Comment: You are so lazy... didn't even check the link that `Fred` gave you, did you?

Comment: Try `$sql= "UPDATE Member SET Address = '$address', Mail='$mail, UserName='$user', Password='$password'");` but I don't know what your WHERE clause should look for. You need to show us your DB schema.

Comment: Have you not read any tutorials or spent time on Google? @noooooooo You're not going to learn anything and stand at coming back to ask more questions later on.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using MySQL as you didn't specify the SQL flavour.

If you are trying to **`INSERT`** into the table the correct Syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO `Member` (`Address`, `Mail`, `UserName`, `Password`)
VALUES ('$address', '$mail', '$user', '$password');
```

If you are trying to **`UPDATE`** the row the Syntax is:

```
UPDATE `Member` SET 
    `Address`  = '$address',
    `Mail`     = '$mail',
    `UserName` = '$user',
    `Password` = '$password'
WHERE ...;
```

You will need to set a **`WHERE`** condition otherwise it will **`UPDATE`** all rows in the table.

Comment: Good luck with this. I hope you haven't fallen into the proverbial "can of worms". But +1 nonetheless ;-)

Comment: thx for your help and i have read that link and didnt make sence to me